# Display image from database php

Tags: php, sql, image, blob

I have prolem displaying images from a table in my database the image is stored in a blob. This is my code

```
function selectfromdatabase(){
    require "/home/pfrolov/private/connectDB.php";  
    $sql = "SELECT `id`, `name`, `image`, `uploadtime` FROM `images` ORDER BY 
`id` ASC LIMIT 1";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

          $image = $row["image"];
          echo $image;
          echo '<img height="300px" width="300px" src="data:image/png;base64,' $image . '">';
     }
    } else {
      echo "0 results";
    }
    $conn->close();
}
```

When I echo $image it says: /tmp/phpnztKh7 , how can I make it so that  there will be an image?

Comment: `/tmp/phpnztKh7` sounds like you stored the temp file for it, rather than the actual image data from the filename.

Comment: you also have a variable scope issue

Comment: Hi , thanks for answering. It works fine now, but where do you see the scope issue?

Comment: `function selectfromdatabase()` was thinking that a connection might have had to be passed but alas, I stood to be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alas, what I mentioned in comments:

> /tmp/phpnztKh7 sounds like you stored the temp file for it, rather than the actual image data from the filename

is that you most likely used the `['tmp_name']` array name, rather than the `['name']` array name from `$_FILES` during the data storage.

Reference:

- http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php